# What is the correct return statement other than return secondpass?

Tags: java, return

What is the correct return statement other than `return secondpass`?

Why is it possible to `return secondpass` and still be able to have no errors showing up in the IDE **IntelliJ** and be able to run?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    getDurationString(5,2);
}

public static int getDurationString(int minutes, int seconds) {
    if (minutes < 0 || seconds < 0 && seconds > 59) {
        System.out.println("Invalid value");
    }
    int hourtomin = (60/minutes);
    int secondspass = (seconds/seconds);
    System.out.println(hourtomin + "hours" + secondspass + "seconds");
    return secondspass;
}
```

Comment: `60 / 5` is `12` ... pretty sure this isn't what you'd be expecting.  My suggestion is to start with a piece of paper and pen and try and figure out the mathematics of what you "seem" to be trying.  Also ask yourself, if the method is named `getDurationString`, what type of value would you expect it to return

Comment: It would be nice to know the specific errors you're getting: specifically, whether it's a compiler error or a runtime exception, as well as the specific error. Can you please [edit] this question with more details about the error?

Comment: Also, one improvement suggestion: don't rely on operator precedence in your `if` block: use parentheses to make your code clearer to others. Finally, could you please [edit] in details of what the `getDurationString` method is supposed to calculate and return?

Comment: `seconds < 0 && seconds > 59` can never be true.

Answer (score 0):

The most logical thing to return would be the duration string from a method called getDurationString. So I would change the return type to a String (as MadProgrammer was hinting). Also, since the method gives no indication it's going to print something, style would say let the output be handled by the caller. Finally, to answer the other question, the IDE will happily let you return an int (secondspass) from the method with return type int, even if it's not what you want or if the calculation is not correct.

I tweaked the calculations and the checking a little to convert the seconds to minutes first(in case the seconds cause the minutes to have more than an hour -- my doing because I wanted to allow seconds > 59), then break the minutes down into hours and seconds (plus the original seconds). Code follows (I also tried to camel case variables; notice, too, that since the passed variables are primitive types, I can safely modify them without side effects to the caller).

```
public class TimeString {

public static String getDurationString(int minutes, int seconds) {
    //since this method is called get, having a side-effect like printing something is undesirable
    if (minutes < 0 || seconds < 0) { //enhanced to handle seconds > 59
        return "Invalid value";
    }
    //handle any seconds that could be minutes
    minutes += seconds / 60;
    seconds %= 60;
    int hours = (minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds = (seconds + 60 * minutes);
    return hours + " hours " + seconds + " seconds"; //note spaces so things look nice, you asked for hours and seconds, hours, minutes, and seconds is more usual
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(getDurationString(105, 900));
}
}
```

ADDITIONAL THOUGHT:
Using hours, seconds and no minutes for a duration seems very unconventional. Here is what the code looks like if one keeps the minutes as minutes rather than converting them to seconds.

```
public class TimeString {

public static String getDurationString(int minutes, int seconds) {
    //since this method is called get, having a side-effect like printing something is undesirable
    if (minutes < 0 || seconds < 0) { //enhanced to handle seconds > 59
        return "Invalid value";
    }
    //handle any seconds that could be minutes
    minutes += seconds / 60;
    seconds %= 60; //and mod by 60 to get any remaining seconds
    int hours = (minutes / 60);//handle whether there are full hours from the minutes
    minutes %= 60;// and mod by 60 to get the remaining minutes
    //removed line converting minutes back to seconds
    return hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds"; //note spaces so things look nice, you asked for hours and seconds, hours, minutes, and seconds is more usual
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(getDurationString(95, 79));// should become 1 hours 36 minutes 19 seconds
}
}
```